# How accurate can location services be on Android

Tags: android, location

I'm creating an application that needs to be very accurate such that when an individual is walking past a certain building, it will provide them  with information regarding that building.  I was wondering could this be accurate enough using the Android Location API?  What technical challenges should I consider?

Edit: I am using a HTC Sensation XE although i'm not sure what chip it uses for GPS

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think there are any guarantees on that.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple variable factors here:
1. GPS hardware itself.
2. Even if the GPS hardware is good,you cannot assume to have very good accuracy since GPS works on "Line of sight"...so if there is lots of trees/high buildings/or anything that could possibly cover the satellite from the GPS receiver would decrease the accuracy of the location determined
3.Time and location---Not all GPS satellites are available in all places at all times...and the accuracy depends on the number of available satellites currently above the user in the sky(to say in lay man terms).
4.The speed of the user.This is more to do with the polling time rather than the GPS accuracy,If say the user is moving in a high speed train,it practically becomes impossible to exactly poll the GPS for the location at that required time thus missing the building. 

You might want to understand on how GPS works and this is more of a GPS technology limtation rather than Androids.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the answer depends on your GPS hardware. However, do not expect accuracy of a few meters.

See here for a similar question and some aspects for accuracy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852790/1127492

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567443/how-accurate-is-android-gps), accuracy of Android phones' GPS can vary from around 5 to 50 meters, but it mostly depends on the performance of the GPS chips, which has nothing to do with the OS per se.

According to the [location API doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html), you can also try to use the cell towers and wi-fi hotspot for location, but this will typically be even less precise.